# Какой знак препинания необходимо поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

**Если я не в сети( ) звоните отцу Николая( ) Петру.**

Comment: очепятка... очепятка... очепятка.

Answer (score 2):

*Если я не в Сети* - обязательная запятая, отделяющая придаточное от главного.

*Звоните отцу Николая Петру* (главное) - запятая факультативна, но я бы не стала переутяжелять предложение знаками, если можно без. Поставленная, она будет означать уточнение (подразумевая, что у Николая не один отец; скажем, отчима он тоже называет отцом; это чтоб не запутаться).

Comment: Мне кажется, запятая после имени поможет избежать неоднозначности (кто-то может предположить, что Николай Петру - имя и фамилия нашего героя)

Comment: Имхо, фамилия Петру произносилась бы с ударением на первом слоге... О_о

Comment: Я тоже так думаю. И это возможно, ведь ударение в тексте не стоит.